# How can I find the first four consecutive numbers with four free denominators?

Tags: vba, numbers

The first two consecutive numbers with two free denominators are:

```
14 = 2 × 7
15 = 3 × 5
```

The first three consecutive numbers with three free denominators are:

```
644 = 2 × 7 × 23
645 = 3 × 5 × 43
646 = 2 × 17 × 19
```

How can I find the first four consecutive numbers with exactly four free denominators?

Comment: What is a "free" denominator? That isn't a standard adjective in mathematics in this context and you don't seem to be talking about denominators. You seem to be looking for runs of square-free numbers which have a specified number of prime factors.

Comment: Also -- by `basic` do you literally mean a solution in a dialect of the Basic programming language, or do you mean that you regard this as a sort of basic question about numbers?

Comment: Post to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JohnColeman sorry i wasnt clear enough, i was thinking about visual basic and free denominator is a number that can be devided only with number 1 and himself, i dont know how it is said in english, thanks for answer

Comment: The words are 'Prime Factors'  And see [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/202782) for a method that can serve as a backbone to finding the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the case that 644 = 2 x 7 x 23. Rather 644 = 2 x 2 x 7 x 23 -- you are looking for numbers which have distinct prime divisors *which might be repeated*. In fact, 1309, 1310, 1311 are the first 3 numbers which have 3 distinct non-repeated factors, and it is impossible to do that for 4 since any run of 4 successive numbers will have a repeated factor of 4.

To solve the problem of finding 4 successive numbers each of which has 4 distinct (albeit possibly repeated) prime factors, you can use a modified version of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), one which keeps track of the number of distinct divisors:

```
Function SieveK(n As Long, k As Long) As Long
    'Implements a modified Sieve of Erasthones
    'to return the first of k successive numbers
    'less than or equal to n, each of which has
    'k distinct prime factors.
    'Returns -1 if no such number exists

    Dim nums As Variant
    Dim i As Long, p As Long
    Dim run As Long
    Dim limit As Long
    Dim primes As Variant

    primes = Array(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13) 'small primes
    p = 1
    For i = 0 To k - 2
        p = p * primes(i)
    Next i
    limit = Int(1 + n / p)

    ReDim nums(2 To n) As Long
    p = 2 'first prime
    Do While p < limit
        'mark subsequent multiples of p by adding 1
        For i = 2 * p To n Step p
            nums(i) = nums(i) + 1
        Next i
        'find next p -- which will be next 0
        p = p + 1
        Do While nums(p) <> 0
            p = p + 1
        Loop
    Loop
    'At this stage, all numbers are marked. 
    'primes are marked by 0 and composites are marked 
    'by the number of distinct prime factors.
    'Check for a run of k ks
    run = 0
    For i = 2 To n
        If nums(i) = k Then
            run = run + 1
            If run = k Then 'we have a winner!
                SieveK = i - k + 1
                Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            'reset run counter
            run = 0
        End If
    Next i
    SieveK = -1
End Function
```

`SieveK(10^6,4)` evaluates to 134043 in less than a second. The function doesn't yield the factorization of this or the next 3 numbers, but those are easy to find.  `SieveK(10^8,5)` evaluates to -1, so there isn't a run less than 100 million of 5 consecutive numbers each of which has 5 different prime factors.

Remark: in an earlier version of this answer I had a logic flaw (which didn't prevent the output from being correct). Namely -- I had sieved only to the square root of n, though if e.g. a number m looks like 2x3x5xp with p prime then m could have 4 distinct prime factors even though p might exceed the square root of n. I revised the algorithm to take care of this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
`134043 = 3 x 7 x 13 x 491`
`134044 = 2 x 23 x 31 x 47`
`134045 = 5 x 17 x 19 x 83`
`134046 = 2 x 3 x 11 x 677`

Comment: thank you so much sir, can you please tell me how did you get to this cuz i need to write the code in visual basic, best regards

Comment: Sorry but I Just found it online after googling for fun. This page offers an approach maybe you can translate into VBA: http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-47-distinct-prime-factors/
The code linked by Scott Craner above looks promising too.
It may take forever in VBA, an optimization approach may be smarter, xpress-mp claims to have a way to restrict decision variables to take only prime number values.